# Pandas: How to drop list of indices of Level 2 in MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a Pandas dataframe shaped as follows:

[Dataframe Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmHjP.png)

What I would like to do is for every index of Level 1 (2000, ... , 2020), drop the Level 2 indices that are contained in a list,  'inactive stations', effectively removing the rows associated to the indices from the dataset.

My code for this is as follows:

```html
#getting list of level 1 one values without duplicates
level_1_values = list(dict.fromkeys(ds2.index.get_level_values(0).tolist()))

#removing all level 2 indices in inactive_stations 
for value in level_1_values:
    #getting Level 2 indices for each Level 1 index
    station_list = ds2.loc[[value]].index.get_level_values(1).tolist()
    #calculating list of indices to be removed, 'inactive_sessions'
    inactive_stations = set(station_list).difference(set(active_stations))
    #dropping rows associated to inactive stations
    ds2.index.set_levels(ds2.loc[[value]].index.levels[1].drop(inactive_stations), level=1)
```

I get the following error:

ValueError: On level 1, code max (33721) >= length of level (22196). NOTE: this index is in an inconsistent state

Comment: Please edit this question to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.